# Dependency downloaded from Maven Central is free from Malware?

Tags: maven, malware

I am new to Maven and trying to use it for Android build. I have this doubt in my mind which was also triggered by Jason Van Zyl's interview [here](http://pages.citebite.com/j5t4a2d3bgjy).

**My Question**

How to ensure that the dependency we have downloaded from Maven Central is free from Malware or is not corrupted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never be sure it is free from malware, i.e. it is always possible.

Maven Central host open source projects so the source code is always available from somewhere, so if you need to be sure of malware free and also sure of compatible licensing terms you should download the source and build it yourself and not use Maven Central.

I am sure if an artifact did have malware in it the people running Maven Central have a policy to be contacted to investigate such things and deal with it.

...

Re corruption free.  Maven makes use of hash digests for many things to ensure corruption free data, your Maven client and Maven Repository can be configured to always validate.  Files on the server also usually have a *.md5 or *.sha1 URL of the data checksum.

Also JARs themselves have intrinsic checksums.  They are based on ZIP files and these do have a checksum scheme that should detect most corruption.  The ZIP directory is always at the end of the file so short/truncated files will also be detected.

Obviously these mechanisms are not 100% reliable but maybe considered 99.99% reliable.

...

As a software producer putting things up on Maven central.  I would urge you to always SIGN your JARs.  This is a mechanism that allows each independent software producer to sign the original JAR they produce and then distribute it via any mechanism across the internet.  Any user can (theoretically) download it from any source and be able to verify that it has not been tampered with.

Unfortunately Maven Central does not have a policy to ensure source code is available alongside binaries, or have a policy enforcing JAR signing.  So from a security stand point Maven Central is useful to get things going with your local development but if you do care about security do not use it.

You nee to implement your own security policy (or pay someone else) to implement it on your behalf.

To manage your secured environment you might wish to take a look at one of the Maven repositories you can run on your local network such as Sonatype Nexus (this comes in open-source and free edition with most features enabled).

...

NB I did not read the link you provided yet will do now.

Comment: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to build software yourself instead of downloading it from the Central repository is an amazingly bad idea. Uploads to central are very closely guarded and you can enable strict checksum  checks for every download Maven does in your settings.xml.

If the checksum matches you will have the exact copy of artifacts in central and they are very closely monitored during uploads and do not change once uploaded.

In addition you would only use Central indirectly via a company controlled repository manager like Nexus and if you need more security, license and audit tooling and reporting you would look at tools like Sonatype Nexus Professional and Sonatype Insight or similar products.

Comment: Cite me the legal contract that Maven Central provides the users to guarantee my enterprise will never receive malware from it.This contract needs to allow me to sue a party for damages if that claim is found to be untrue, this is what serious business needs.If your enterprises needs malware assurance you should download the source code, audit it yourself, built it yourself and deploy it into your own secure repository. You should not use central. Uploads to central is not very well protected in this way almost anyone can create a new OSS project and upload anything by following due process.

Comment: Well.. there are plenty of tools to go down and examine the source if you really need to go to that level. However that should NOT mean you rebuild from source.

Comment: The good aspects of your answer we agree on. But we seem to disagree on your unique point that auditing software yourself is a bad idea in the context of security. It is the audit trail that is important and whilst Maven Central does have procedures in place to reduce the possibility of malware it does not eliminate that possibility nor provide any risk guarantees to its consumers. So if the question asker is running a bank or utility company (a serious business) please use a better audit trail for malware assurance than that which Maven Central provides. Take from this the risk is not zero.

Comment: Obviously you would not use Central directly. You would use a repository manager like Nexus Professional with all the necessary audit, security and control features on top of the data and artifacts central provides. My concern would just be that doing it yourself is a lot of work and you most likely would not do as good a job at what existing expertise and tooling provides. Don't reinvent the wheel. Check out Sonatype Insight and more if you are concerned.   And yes .. lots of banks and other VERY security minded companies do just that.